# Random.py doesn't collect in CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x

py doesn't collet in CMD and this problem it's just about random library.
I get this error.

```
C:\Users\RayanTech>pip install random
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for random
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLfYS.png)

Comment: `random` is part of the Python standard library. You don't install it.

Comment: `random` is builtin with python

Answer (score 1):

The **error message** you get at running the `pip install random` command, occurs because of **2 reasons**:

- **It's already a built-in library**: This library is already a part of **every python3** installation - so you don't need to install it with pip.
- **Doesn't exist on PYPI:** `PYPI` is the Python Package Index and lists available libraries, that you can install - but the package with the name `random` doesn't exist.

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, there's two different things called packages: _import packages_, which are collections of importable modules that you specify at `import` statements, and _distribution packages_ (typically shortened to just _distributions_ to avoid ambiguity), which are collections of installable import packages with associated metadata. `pip` works on _distributions_. Hence _"ERROR: No matching **distribution** found for random"_ not _"No matching package"_. Distribution names also need not (and quite often don't) match the name of the import package(s) they provide.